# retrieve Invocation Statistics with twiddle

Tags: jboss

Is there a way to get Invocation Statistics using twiddle command line tool

I tried

`twiddle.sh get "jboss.j2ee:jndiName=jaas/foo/bar/MyBean,service=EJB" InvokeStats`

but I get java.io.NotSerializableException: org.jboss.invocation.InvocationStatistics.

Is jboss web-console the only way to collect statistics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After googling a bit I found an answer. Actually, the correct command is

`twiddle.bat --user="user" --password="pwd" get "jboss.management.local:name=jaas/foo/bar/MyBean,J2EEServer=Local,EJBModule=my_ejb.jar,J2EEApplication=my_ear.ear,j2eeType=StatelessSessionBean" stats`

It's necessary to add jboss-management.jar to the classpath as well, twiddle forgot to do this.